Create an audience from filtering multiple Data extensions
Is there a way to filter off multiple data extensions without using SQL and without relying on filtering in Journey builder? I know that contact builder can link the data extensions but it doesn't create a new one and it would require filtering in Journey builder, but am I missing something here?

Does the data come from Sales Cloud? If so, there are better options.

Yes it is indeed from Sales cloud. What are your thoughts?

In Sales Cloud, use a Report or Campaign  to build your list/audience and then send via MC from there. Reports are easier to deal with. In MC this is known as "Salesforce Send" - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_salesforce_sends_in_marketing_cloud.htm&type=5

so that is what we do currently but we want to move this process to MC as we'll be able to filter on consent there which we can't in SC.

Having consent in Sales Cloud is the recommended architecture. Even if you have it in MC now, sending consent to SC is a fraction of the effort versus sending all that other data to MC.

You can utilise filtered data extensions and data relationships in Email Studio. It is not a perfect solution - it only supports quite simple combinations of data extensions, and will not allow you to join data extensions on more than 2 levels (as described in e.g. this thread).
You could use a (paid) 3rd party feature such as DE Select, which will put a more user friendly UI on top of Automation Studio, allowing you to build segmentation using drag and drop functionality, not requiring you to write any SQL.

Yes I've raised that we would need SQL and to consider DE Select, it's just that our SF solutions architect was implying that it is possible to use contact builder but I just can't think of a way.

Contact builder is not connected to Data Relationships.
In contact builder you link the DEs together just to support the Journey Builder UI.
With Data Relationships, you also link DEs, but those are meant to be used with point & click filters.
